# How to test my app with firebase database without affecting the live database?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using firebase database at the backend. I am working on next version of my app and the problem is whenever i test my app or make any changes to firebase database it reflects on my live database which is undesirable. What is the workaround for this? How can I test and debug my app without disturbing the current database used by the users?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The common approach is to set up additional projects for your test, and possibly for development too, environments.

It's easy to switch environments with the `firebase use` command.

> ```
> $ firebase use --add
> $ ? Which project do you want to add? (Use arrow keys)
>   my-production-project
> > my-staging-project
>   my-dev-project
> ? What alias do you want to use for this project? (e.g. staging) staging
> Created alias staging my-staging-project.
> Now using alias staging (my-staging-project)
> ```

For a full explanation of the steps, see the blog post [Deploy to multiple environments with Firebase Hosting](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/07/deploy-to-multiple-environments-with.html) (it applies to all of Firebase, not just hosting), and the [reference documentation for managing project aliases](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/#managing_project_aliases).